# IIS Integrated Security Remote Sql Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, blazor-server-side, web-hosting

I try to host a Blazor-App (server-side) on an IIS which should connect to a remote SQL-Server using integrated security.

I found this description:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bsz5788z(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

As explained in this articel, I've enabled "Basic Authentication" and I'm able to login to the website with my AD-Account, but when it comes to creating a Sql-Connection with integreated security my AD-Credentials doesn't get forwarded to the SQL-Server.

I do have a own ApplicationPool for this. This one is running with Identity "Network Service". At the MSDN-Articel I found no description what I have to select there and as it seems the Network Service-Account gets forwarded to the SQL-Server instead of my AD-User.

What do I have to do that always the current logged in AD-User gets forwarded?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should let go of the idea of passing through the authentication from the website all the way through to the database. Your users shouldn't have direct DB access, that should always go through something that you control, such as an API or website. Instead, have your application pool run as a user that has sufficient privilege to do everything it needs to do in the DB, and then have your users just authenticate to the website, which should handle authorization.

Comment: It's an windows-based intranet webapp

Comment: @mason is warning us is because a sneaky developer (hacker, etc) could abuse this by "borrowing" the user's credentials to do whatever the developer wants, without the user's knowledge. For example "Hey domain admin, could you look at this page on our intranet?" ... and now you are a domain admin too.

Comment: The article that you linked does talk about Kerberos trust between two servers. That can be connected in Active Directory. Have you configured that yet?